# Crontab Operation not permitted

Tags: macos, catalina, cron

I have the following crontab on my mac OS Catalina 10.15.1 :

```
* * * * * /Users/username/Desktop/cronjob.sh > /Users/username/Desktop/cronjob.log 2>&1
```

Within the command file is:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /tmp/foo
```

However I was left with the following line inside `cronjob.log`

```
/bin/bash: /Users/username/Desktop/cronjob.sh: Operation not permitted
```

---

Why is operation not permitted event though the permissions for `cronjob.sh` is set to `+x`?

Comment: Which version of macOS are you using? Does the error also occur if your bash script only contains `touch /tmp/foo`?

Comment: Yes, the problem persists.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the minimal script then, to prevent people from suspecting python issues. Also, which version of macOS?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, am using mac OS Catalina 10.15.1, included in the edited question

Comment: I found errors for my crontab in /var/mail/$USER

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In your case you have to add `cron` as "parent" app to the user's Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access apps/execs.

Depending where to read the script from and where to write the log file to, you have to add `cron` to the Full Disk Access apps. Almost all default folders in the user's home are protected (Documents/Downloads/Desktop - I haven't checked Pictures/Movies/Music but I think they are protected too and obviously the wrong folders to add shell scripts or log files) by Catalina's system policy.

If the script and the log reside in user created and thus unprotected folders (e.g. the script in ~/bin and the log file in ~/log) it works without adding cron to the Full Disk Access group.

To add the exception:

1. click the <kbd>+</kbd> button
2. hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
3. enter `/usr/sbin`
4. double click the `cron` file.

---

You can check this kind of errors by opening Console.app and searching for the shebanged exec in the script (here `bash`):

```
error   15:19:00.369105+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bash(4556) System Policy: deny(1) file-write-data /Users/user/Desktop/test/cronjob2.log
error   15:19:00.379093+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bash(4555) System Policy: deny(1) file-read-data /Users/user/Desktop/cronjob.sh
```

In the examples above `cron` **wasn't added** to the Full Disk Access group.

*cronjob2* was run from an unprotected folder ~/bin but tries to write the log file to the protected folder ~/Desktop/test/. So no read error but a write error.

*cronjob* was run from a protected folder ~/Desktop and tries to write the log file to the protected folder ~/Desktop/. So a read error.

Interestingly both log files are created - the first one (cronjob2.log) is empty though.

Comment: Do I add `cron` or `crontab` to Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access apps/execs?

Comment: @Tian You have to add cron to this group

Comment: I could not access `/usr/sbin` when using the GUI to add `cron`. Also, the issue persisted when my script and log resided in the Desktop

Comment: @Tian hit cmd-shift-. to make invisible items visible

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. Any idea if this will also work with `launchctl` jobs, or if there is another app you need to give access to?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on Big Sur also

Comment: shift-command-G lets you enter any path without having to expose the hidden files and folders. Works in any finder or document picker window.

Comment: Is there anyway to add `cron` to a specified "Files & Folder access" rather than "Full disk access"?

Comment: I tried doing this, but it didn't seem to work. Then I realized that even though I was killing all the windows in iTerm, the application wasn't actually closing. When I killed the application and re-ran it, it finally worked. Thought I would point this out in case anyone else had the same issue.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you for this.  Very clear on how identify the problem and how to fix it.  I'd had a Mac mini running backups at night for a dozen years, no problem, but when it finally gave up the ghost, the replacement only wanted to run the scripts manually at the terminal!

Comment: I was breaking my head debugging this on my new M1 Macbook then remembered the infuriating csrutil nonsese that I have to do on new computers, which gave me a hint here.

Comment: If only there was an applescript to automate this.

Comment: As of writing this, `cron` now lives in `/usr/sbin/cron`, find it with `which cron`, Sonoma `14.2.1`