# cronjobs do not run

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, cron

I have recently switched from Ubuntu to MacOS. I tried to run the exact same cronjobs I ran on Ubuntu before, however they don't, and after trying to figure out if the crontab entries might have any errors, I more and more had the suspicion that cronjobs don't run on my MBP at all, so I added this line to `crontab -e`:

`*/15 * * * * touch /Users/<my-user>/cronjob-success-"$(date +%Y%m%d)".txt`

I'd expect it to run every 15 min (xxh15, xxh30, ...), however no new files appear. I also don't see any logs indicating cronjob runs.

The file exists in `/usr/lib/cron/tabs/<my-user>`. What am I doing wrong that this doesn't work?

I am on Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: You will need to [grant permissions for command line tools to run](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378558/5472) on Catalina.

Comment: I apologize. My comment was entered as an answer and come code has decided it’s a comment and not an answer. See https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3969 for details.

Comment: Also, did you add terminal app to the full disk entitlements and log out / restart?

Comment: Wasn't cron depreciated for launchd a few years back?

Comment: I added iTerm which I actually use, but also the Terminal app, as well as `cron` and `crontab` to `Full Disk Access`. I hadn't restarted, but did now. No success.

Comment: `cron` treats `%` characters in the command as line delimiters; you need to escape them like ...`date +\%Y\%m\%d`... for the command to work.

Comment: @SteveChambers I have it on good authority it’s still in the Big Sur betas!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend a couple of things:

1. Make sure `cron` has **Full Disk Access** in the Privacy tab of `System Preferences` (see s/s below)
   [image]

2. When creating commands in `crontab`, help yourself out by writing errors generated by `stderr` to an output file using `2>&1`, and using full pathnames (your `cron` job **does not** run w/ same environment as your user does);

EXAMPLE:

```shell
seamus@Dung-Pro ~ % crontab -l 

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/touch /Users/seamus/scripts/cronjob-success-"$(date)".txt
```

#### SOME OTHER IDEAS:

1. crontab guru: https://crontab.guru/
2. not always necessary, but using full path to command is a good habit!
3. it often helps to re-direct `stderr` (aka `2`) to a file for review when things go wrong
4. re-direct may be done as follows:
   `>> /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1`

   This redirects `stdout` to `/home/pi/cronjoblog` **and** redirects `stderr` to `stdout`; i.e. both streams will be written to the file.
5. Finally, wrt the specific command in your question: that does not run for me either - it has something to do with the formatting specified for the date command - date with no formatting works fine. If you need to use that specific format, you should try @GordonDavisson comment to your question.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this. Others were partly right, but your answer is the most complete. In fact I had (and partly still have) a series of issues. Firstly, indeed I had to give `Full Disk Access` to `cron`. Secondly, it my test cronjob was indeed faulty and did not work. Your example did! I also logged stderr now and got `/bin/sh: flock: command not found`. I use flock to not run the same rsync twice. I am aware that it's original a linux thing, but I have installed https://github.com/discoteq/flock and the rsync works with flock from my user. I suspect cron uses another user and that breaks it?

Comment: If I type `which flock` I get `/usr/local/bin/flock`. I am not sure what to do with this though.

Comment: So, turns out I ignored one part of your answer. I had to specify the full path as you said (`/usr/local/bin/flock`) and it worked :) Thank you!

Comment: @YanickNedderhoff: Glad that helped. `cron` is an invaluable tool, IMHO. The key to getting results is (as in most things), is [understanding its limitations](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/MyCrontabDoesntWork.md). And thanks for the feedback - I should have made that business with the full path specification more prominent.

Comment: I wish I could give you both more than one upvote. Super helpful explanations how to get to the right set of fixes.

Answer (score 2):

- [grant permissions for cron and possible the terminal apps / command line tools to run](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378558/5472) on Catalina.
- check for full paths everywhere...
- consider putting your commands in a script so you can debug them and avoid needing to escape characters like % or run `cron` in debug/test mode

Comment: I did read about this before, but it does not seem to fix the issue in my case. I did at `/usr/sbin/cron` to `Full Disk Access`, but still the jobs don't run.

Comment: Also, where do cronjob logs show up so I can try to have a look?

Comment: @YanickNedderhoff I’ll have to dig for that. I converted 100% of my jobs to `launchctl` so I don’t need to futz with all the setup.

Comment: launchctl is new to me. I might move to that but first would like to get my existing setup migrated to MacOS.

Comment: I’ve edited my short answer in case it helps others in hindsight.  Great work with Seamus - they are ace on the command line along with a few others here :)

Comment: @YanickNedderhoff: IMHO, `launchctl` is horribly arcane without the help of [`LaunchControl`](http://www.soma-zone.com).