# Task scheduled as a cronjob not executing

Tags: zsh, cron, macos

On my Macos 11.6.1, I want to execute a script 'task1.zsh' with the following content

```
#!/bin/zsh

/usr/bin/touch /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/hello.txt
echo hello >> /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/hello.txt
```

the file `task1.zsh` has the following permissions:

```
-rwxr-x--x   1 user  staff   116B Jun 18 00:15 task1.zsh*
```

I inserted the following task with cronjob (with the following output of the command `crontab -l`:

```
* * * * * /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/task1.zsh
```

with this cronjob, however the file "hello.txt" is not created nor populated.
I also tried to replace

```
* * * * * /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/task1.zsh
```

by:

```
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/ && ./task1.zsh
```

as well as

```
* * * * * /bin/zsh /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/task1.zsh
```

or

```
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs /bin/zsh task1.zsh
```

without success.

However If I had the following other task to the cronjob list:

```
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs && /bin/zsh task1.zsh
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs && echo check >> cron1.log
```

the file `cron1.log` gets created and gets populated by the string "check" (but the file `hello.txt` does not get created nor populated)

What am I doing wrong?

N.B. I originally asked the question on the main stackoverflow website (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76499197/task-scheduled-as-a-cronjob-not-executing?noredirect=1#comment134921903_76499197) and I was advised to post the question on Ask Different.

**EDIT 1**

I replaced :

```
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs && /bin/zsh task1.zsh
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs && echo check >> cron1.log
```

```
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs && /bin/zsh task1.zsh
* * * * * echo “Hello” >> /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/hello.txt
```

and indeed it worked

**SOLUTION**

As mentionned in the comment I went to Security and Privacy and granted full disk access to cron and it worked according to [Crontab Operation not permitted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378553/crontab-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: Start diagnosing by changing the line in your crontab to be `* * * * * echo “Hello” >> /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/hello.txt`.  That will skip creating a new subshell to run the script. Does it work?  Also, is there a reason you’re not using launchd?

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @Allan. As I use Linux in parallel I want to use code which works for both linux and macos. I replaced :

```
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs && /bin/zsh task1.zsh
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs && echo check >> cron1.log
```

```
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs && /bin/zsh task1.zsh
* * * * * echo “Hello” >> /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/hello.txt
```
and indeed it worked

Comment: Then we know cron is working.  After looking at your permissions again, try setting the permissions to read and execute for everyone.

Comment: Users' Desktop folders (and Documents and many other places) have special privacy protection in addition to regular file permissions, and you may be running into trouble with that. See ["What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673), ["Crontab Operation not permitted"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378553), ['Why do I get "ls: Desktop: Operation not permitted" when I own Desktop?'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425519), etc.

Comment: ok thank you @Allan for your comment. I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: thank you @GordonDavisson. Indeed, I went to Security and Privacy and granted full disk access to cron and it worked

Comment: @ecjb I'm glad you got it working, but I'd recommend against just turning off protection for cron jobs. It'd be best to move the script & its files to a non-private location, and the second-best option would be to give cron access to just your Documents folder (in the Files and Folders section) rather than full disk access.

Comment: many thanks for your comment @GordonDavisson. What would typically be a "non-private" location on macos?

Comment: @ecjb I don't have a current version of macOS handy for testing, but I think the main locations that're restricted are the Desktop, Documents, and Downloads folders, plus several things under ~/Library. Creating a new top-level folder in your home directory might be the simplest solution.